# apostrophe after "is a ... of the King('s)"?

Tags: grammar, possessives

> Famine is a major concern of the King

If the King is concerned about famine, should the above sentence end "King's" instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for an apostrophe.

Generally there are two forms:

> The king's concerns

> The concerns of the king.

The double possessive does exist, and is a curious thing. It is sometimes used without thought when the alternative might be an ambiguous construction. See [A Guide to Double Possessives](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/double-possessives-genitives#:%7E:text=The%20double%20possessive%2C%20usually%20using,a%20picture%20of%20my%20friend%27s.%22) for examples of this advanced topic.

In your case, no double possessive is needed. The sentence as quoted is correct without 's.